# What Beethoven Piano Sonata should I choose?

Tags: sonata

I'm a pianist, and I'm currently on 7th grade at my conservatory.

I'm playing Beethoven's *op.78, No.24 Piano Sonata*. It's fine, but I want to choose another Beethoven sonata to train technique, so I can play *op.109 No.30* in 8th grade.

Just to give a sense of what my level of playing is, I'm currently with: *Chopin's Scherzo No.1*, *Bach's WTC Book 1 in G Major and in F Minor*, *Prokofiev's Suggestion Diabolique*, *Ravel's Une Barque Sur L'Océan* (just started, I don't now how hard it will be), and some other *Chopin Études* (*Op.25 No.6* and *No.11*, *Op.10 No.2*).

What sonatas would be both musically and technically useful for this approach (*op.109* next year)?

Comment: When I was in Grade 8, I was scraping with Beethoven's Piano Sonata No. **20**. If you can actually play Chopin's Scherzo No. 1 in B Minor and Prokofiev's Suggestion Diabolique, I say pick anything you want. I speak as someone whose Beethoven's Piano Sonata No. 1 could never get quite polished enough.

Comment: Do you not have a teacher? They may have opinions about areas of your technique and experience that need more exposure. Also, try exploring! When I was in conservatory I worked in the music library and discovered many fun pieces while shelving them.